# Hook to get $_POST variable before save product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there any hook to get the $_POST variable before save/Update the product including metas

Answer (score 1):

**save_post** hook is fired when a post or page is created. This will also work for the product because the product is also stored as a post in woocommerce.

for more details,

- [save_post hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)
- [How can I edit post data before it is saved?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35931/how-can-i-edit-post-data-before-it-is-saved)

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score -1):

```
function _save_data( $post_id ) {
    ob_start();
    print_r($_POST);
    $post_query_content = ob_get_clean();
    throw new ErrorException($post_query_content);
}

add_action( 'save_data', '_save_data' );
```

You can throw new ErrorExpection. Not save way, but it helped me.