# Which hook to modify metadata before save (WooCommerce products)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, hook

I would like to potentially modify metadata (if empty) on a WooCommerce product before it is saved. This metadata is a custom meta field that is not part of WooCommerce. That means I need to check the given metadata first – as opposed to setting a value always, regardless.

- [Which hook to save WooCommerce product meta in WooCommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62379035/2126442)

  - `woocommerce_admin_process_product_object` — Provides a `$product` object but its metadata isn't updated yet. Where would I get the given product data from?
  - `woocommerce_process_product_meta` — Provides just the post-ID – even less info to go on.
  - `save_post_product` — Same.
  - `save_post` — Same.
- [Hook to set product weight on save_post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445796/hook-to-set-product-weight-on-save-post) / `woocommerce_process_product_meta_$product_type` — IIRC, seems to let me see a product but only provides access to special WooCommerce properties, like weight, but not metadata.
- [field_no_prefix_save_pre](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/field_no_prefix_save_pre/) / `{$field_no_prefix}_save_pre` — Does not work for metadata.
- [Hook to get $_POST variable before save product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48022685/hook-to-get-post-variable-before-save-product)

  - [How can I edit post data before it is saved?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35931/how-can-i-edit-post-data-before-it-is-saved) / `wp_insert_post_data` — Lets me filter (modify) the core post-data and access the metadata but not modify the metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty ugly, but this works in my case:

```
function my_save_product_meta( $product ) {

    // only modify if empty; replacement / action is simple enough so that we 
    // need not to worry about sanitization.
    if (
        isset($_POST['my_custom_field']) 
    &&  empty(trim($_POST['my_custom_field']))
    ) {
        $_POST['my_custom_field'] = '0';
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'my_save_product_meta', 10, 1);
```

Works for saving new products as well as updating existing ones.